# How to get history of SQL jobs, that were deleted using DROP and Create To option of that job? Also we do not have backup of msdb

Tags: sql, jobs, agent

How to get history of SQL jobs, that were deleted using DROP and Create To option of that job? Also we do not have backup of msdb.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about? (SQL is a query language, not the name of a specific database product)

Comment: I believe this is not possible

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008 R2 (SP3)